# Why isn't my link passing mysql row values to php edit form?

Tags: php, mysql, forms, edit

I am successfully displaying rows of information from my database on a webpage. I want to be able to edit that data from a form. For some reason, my link to the form is not passing the data though.

Here is the relevant code that displays the data (including the EDIT link):

```
<table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="5" border="1" width="560">
<tr style="text-align:center">
<td style="text-align:left ; width:175px">Player Name</td>
<td>Team</td>
<td>Pass Yds</td>
<td>Pass TDs</td>
<td>Int Thrown</td>
<td>Rush Yds</td>
<td>Rush TDs</td>
<td></td>
</tr>
<?php
    $result = mysql_query("SELECT ID, Player, Team, Pass_Yds, Pass_TDs, Int_Thrown, Rush_Yds, Rush_TDs, Total_Fantasy_Pts FROM ff_projections WHERE Position = 'QB' ORDER BY ID;");

    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
    {
    ?>

    <tr style="text-align:center">
    <td style="text-align:left"><? echo $row['Player']; ?></td>
    <td><? echo $row['Team']; ?></td>
    <td><? echo $row['Pass_Yds']; ?></td>
    <td><? echo $row['Pass_TDs']; ?></td>
    <td><? echo $row['Int_Thrown']; ?></td>
    <td><? echo $row['Rush_Yds']; ?></td>
    <td><? echo $row['Rush_TDs']; ?></td>
    <td><a href="edit.php?id=<? echo $row['ID']; ?>">Edit</a></td></tr>
<?php
    }
    ?>
</table>
```

and here is the code from edit.php:

```
<?php
// contact to database
$connect = mysql_connect("localhost", "xxx", "xxx") or die ("Error , check your server connection.");
mysql_select_db("xxx");
$ID=$_GET['ID'];

$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM ff_projections WHERE ID = '$ID'") or die ("Error in query");
$row=mysql_fetch_array($result);
?>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Untitled Document</title>
</head>

<body>

<form name="edit" method="post" action="confirm.php">
<input name="ID" type="hidden" id="ID" value="<? echo $row['ID']; ?>">
<table width="560" cellspcing="0" cellpadding="5" border="0">
<tr style="text-align:center">
<td style="text-align:left ; width:175px">Player Name</td>
<td>Team</td>
<td>Pass Yds</td>
<td>Pass TDs</td>
<td>Int Thrown</td>
<td>Rush Yds</td>
<td>Rush TDs</td>
<td></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td><? echo $row['Player']; ?></td>
<td><? echo $row['Team']; ?></td>
<td><input class="edit" name="Pass_Yds" type="text" id="Pass_Yds" value="<? echo $row['Pass_Yds']; ?>"></td>
<td><input class="edit" name="Pass_TDs" type="text" id="Pass_TDs" value="<? echo $row['Pass_TDs']; ?>"></td>
<td><input class="edit" name="Int_Thrown" type="text" id="Int_Thrown" value="<? echo $row['Int_Thrown']; ?>"></td>
<td><input class="edit" name="Rush_Yds" type="text" id="Rush_Yds" value="<? echo $row['Rush_Yds']; ?>"></td>
<td><input class="edit" name="Rush_TDs" type="text" id="Rush_TDs" value="<? echo $row['Rush_TDs']; ?>"></td>
<td><input type="submit" name="Submit" value="Submit"></td>
</tr>
</table>
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

I know much of this code is deprecated. Once I get this version working, I'll turn my attention to shoring up the code - using the mysqli API most likely.

In the meantime, any help with this would be most appreciated.

Comment: SQL injection alert!!! `example.com?ID=1' AND 1=1 '`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

PHP is case sensitive (most of the time). So

```
$ID=$_GET['ID'];
```

needs to be

```
$ID=$_GET['id'];
```

Comment: Even though the field name in my db is ID (and not id)?

Comment: Yes. In that line of code you are referring to a PHP variable, not anything related to your database column.

Comment: Correct, the $_GET variable name has nothing to do with your database. You associate it's value, not it's name with your query.

Comment: It worked! And thank you for explaining the logic behind it. Understanding why I'm changing something really helps me out a lot.